# setEditable using ActionListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

Clicking the button should toggle between setting the textfield as editable or not. When the GUI opens the textfield should be editable.

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)
{
    if(inputField.setEditable() == (true))
    {
        inputField.setEditable(false);
    }
    else
    {
        inputField.setEditable(true);
        resultMessage.setText("");
        resultMessage.setText("Edit Button Pressed");
    }
```

What am i doing wrong here?

I know that the else statement is right just the start of the IF is wrong, i'm not sure where i'm going wrong.

---

Additional question:

```
public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent evt)
{
    if(inputField.isEditable() == (true))
    {
        inputField.setEditable(false);
    }
    else
    {
        inputField.setEditable(true);
        inputField.setText("");
        resultMessage.setText("Edit Button Pressed");
    }  

    if(inputField.getBackground() == Color.RED)
    {
        inputField.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    } 
    else
    {
        inputField.setBackground(Color.RED);
        resultMessage.setText("Colour Button Pressed");
    }

}
```

I now currently have 2 IFs but obviously the first IF will stop the second IF from working how do i get around this so that when i press one button that will do the setEditable section and when i press the other button it will do my change colour?

Comment: *"What am i doing wrong here?*" Without wanting to be factious, I'd say you're not reading the JavaDocs

Comment: Please don't delete your original question or code, for if you do, our answers become irrelevant, and the question and answers are not helpful for coders who in the future have similar problems. I have reverted your question back and added additional information. This in truth should be a new stackoverflow question as it is completely different from the original.

Comment: @MadProgrammer the JavaDocs are so confusing i just cannot get my head round the majority of them if i'm honest with you, i find the comment insulting, i clearly have read them just i'm still struggling therefore asked for help on here.

Comment: @MadProgrammer's advice is sound. Getting an understanding from the JavaDocs is a learned skill, and like any other, it will get better with practice, so don't give up, and keep at it, reading them often, and you *will* get better at this. If they confuse you, then best you bring up any specific points of confusion up when asking your questions here.

Comment: @KeithBurton With all due respect, the comment isn't meant to be insulting but is meant as a reminder that the doc's, tutorials and internet are there as a valuable resource to you. If you're still stuck, SO is great place to seek possible solutions, but I would suggest you remind (us bitter old sods) that you have made the effort to solve the problem yourself in some meaningful manner, that's all ;)

Answer (score 3):

You're checking if `setEditable()` is true which really makes no sense; after all, it returns void and requires a boolean parameter. The bigger problem is that you shouldn't be checking the editable status via a "*setter*" field but rather a "*getter*" field, here `isEditable()`

```
if (inputField.isEditable()) {
   //....
} else {
   //...
}
```

As MadProgrammer points out, this information is all readily available in the Java API, something you'll want to get *very* familiar with.

---

Edit, regarding your new question:

> I now currently have 2 IFs but obviously the first IF will stop the second IF from working how do i get around this so that when i press one button that will do the setEditable section and when i press the other button it will do my change colour?

No, the first if/else will have *no effect* on the second if/else block. Your problem lies elsewhere. Consider asking this with additional information as a new question on stackoverflow if still suck.

Also note that this is unnecessarily wordy:

```
if(inputField.isEditable() == (true))
```

and is better written as I have it above:

```
if (inputField.isEditable())
```

Comment: Great that works, also just another quick question, how do i set my code out so that in the actionPerformed section i have more than 1 if statement, because i have 3 buttons on my GUI the first IF overrides the second.

Comment: @KeithBurton: Please clarify and show your best attempt to solve this problem as an addition to your original question.

Comment: @KeithBurton: Code is not readable in comments, and so again, please post your best attempt ***as an addition to your original question.*** Again, please add some more explanation to clarify your problem.

Comment: i've not edited for you so that you can see, my mistake for putting it in the comments.

Comment: @KeithBurton: see edit to answer. You should accept this answer as it answers your original question and if still stuck create a new stackoverflow question for your completely different problem. Consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org).